# Suggestions for relational database for epos receipts

Tags: database-design, relational-database, receipt

I was creating javafx application for simple epos.

At the moment everything is smooth and working. However, I know that in the future I am going to get into troubles because of my database design.

Here is what I have below.[image]

This is where I need help. Do you guys think that this design is OK? Does it require any additional table? Are these relations are OK? Has anyone designed an EPOS database before?

Thanks.

NOTE: this database design is for epos print. User going to login.
Then each time customer orders something;
--> an 'orderID' will be created, and products  will be added to 'Product' table,
--> when it is time to pay, Discount will be made, and payment type button (cash or card) will be chosen. 
-->Finally, when PAY button is clicked all data will be saved into "Product" and "Payment" tables.

Comment: I'm sure this will need more tables, but I don't that SO is the place to answer such a broad question.

Comment: Please read about [mcve]s. (A diagram is equivalent to DDL code.) "EPOS" is just too vague a spec.